# Idiomatic way for finding if an element exists in an nested vector

Tags: clojure

I have modeled my data as embedded vectors. I need to find if an element exists within these vectors. I have the below code which does it correctly. However, I'd like suggestions on a more idiomatic way to do it.

```
(defn exists-in-vector?
  [my-vec my-sym]
  (= my-sym (first my-vec)))

(defn exists-in-vectors?
  [all-vectors my-symbol]
  (empty? (for [first-vector all-vectors
               second-vector first-vector
               third-vector second-vector
               :when (exists-in-vector? third-vector my-symbol)
               :while (exists-in-vector? third-vector my-symbol)]
           true)))

> (exists-in-vectors? [[[[:a 20] [:b :30]] [[:c 20] [:d :30]]]
                      [[[:h 20] [:g :30]] [[:f 20] [:e :30]]]]
                      :a) => true
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is one of the few cases where 'flatten' is exactly what you want:

```
(def vectors [[[[:a 20] [:b :30]] [[:c 20] [:d :30]]] 
             [[[:h 20] [:g :30]] [[:f 20] [:e :30]]]])

(some #{:g} (flatten vectors))
;=> :g

(some #{:k} (flatten vectors))
;=> nil
```

By the way, the definition of flatten is interesting. 
(source flatten) or http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/flatten :

```
(defn flatten
  "Takes any nested combination of sequential things (lists, vectors,
  etc.) and returns their contents as a single, flat sequence.
  (flatten nil) returns nil."
  {:added "1.2"
   :static true}
  [x]
  (filter (complement sequential?)
          (rest (tree-seq sequential? seq x))))
```

Answer (score 5):

A nested vector may be thought of as a tree

```
(def tree [[[[:a 20] [:b :30]] [[:c 20] [:d :30]]] 
           [[[:h 20] [:g :30]] [[:f 20] [:e :30]]]])

(some #(= :a %) (tree-seq vector? identity tree))
;=> true

(some #(= :k %) (tree-seq vector? identity tree))
;=> nil
```

Comment: thanks for the solution ! I am using this sol for other problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
user=> (defn in-nested? [thing elt]
  #_=>   (if (vector? thing) 
  #_=>       (boolean (some #(in-nested? % elt) thing)) 
  #_=>       (= thing elt)))
#'user/in-nested?

user=> (def data [[[[:a 20] [:b :30]] [[:c 20] [:d :30]]] [[[:h 20] [:g :30]] [[:f 20] [:e :30]]]])
#'user/data

user=> (in-nested? data :a)
true
user=> (in-nested? data :c)
true
user=> (in-nested? data :z)
false
user=> (in-nested? data 20)
true
user=> (in-nested? data 40)
false
```